# SQL Server 2008 Casting varchar to datetime

Tags: sql-server, datetime, casting

I'm running into an issue casting a VARCHAR in one table into a DATETIME and then using it in a comparison. The format ('2010-09-02 10:38:31.000') seems to be correct on all of the records, and I can select the data without any problems. However, if I try to use the new datetime in the WHERE clause, I get the error: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

So just to be clear, this works:

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, CAST(Field3 AS DATETIME) AS DateTaken FROM MyTable;
```

That returns all of the data as expected, and there are no null dates. The following fails with the previously mentioned error.

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM MyTable WHERE CAST(Field3 AS DATETIME) > @startDate;
```

I tried using a view to retrieve the data, but it had the same error. Next I tried creating a temporary table for the data like so...

```
SELECT Field1, Field2, CAST(Field3 AS DATETIME) AS Field3 INTO _MyTable;
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM _MyTable WHERE Field3 > @startDate;
```

Which works successfully.

All of my searching just leads to incorrectly formatted dates and / or regional settings causing havok which does not appear to be the cause in my case. I'd rather not create a table every time I need to use a DATETIME cast, so what am I doing wrong here? Help is much appreciated!

Comment: What is the data type of the @startDate variable?  And what value are you using for it?

Comment: In the final version it will be a cast from a VARCHAR as well, but in order to eliminate that CAST as a variable, I have it using GETDATE()

Comment: why not just pass in a datetime and avoid the casting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit # 3..............

```
  select * from test 
  where case isdate(field3) when 1 
        then CAST(field3 as datetime) else null end > @startdate
```

edit # 2..............

I did a test on my db...

```
declare @startdate datetime

select @startdate = '09/1/2010'

Create table test (field1 varchar(50), field2 varchar(50), field3 varchar(50))


insert into test
select 'test' as field1, 'test' as field2, '2010-09-02 10:38:31.000' as field3

insert into test
select 'test2' as field1, 'test2' as field2, '2010-09-02 10:38:31.000' as field3

insert into test
select 'test3' as field1, 'test3' as field2, '2010-10-02 10:38:31.000' as field3

select * from test where CAST(field3 as datetime) > @startdate

select * from test where Convert(datetime, field3) > @startdate

drop table test
```

Results:

```
test    test    2010-09-02 10:38:31.000
test2   test2   2010-09-02 10:38:31.000
test3   test3   2010-10-02 10:38:31.000


test    test    2010-09-02 10:38:31.000
test2   test2   2010-09-02 10:38:31.000
test3   test3   2010-10-02 10:38:31.000
```

changing the startdate param to 10/1/2010
Results:

```
test3   test3   2010-10-02 10:38:31.000

test3   test3   2010-10-02 10:38:31.000
```

1st response.................
Did you try Convert?

```
SELECT Field1, Field2 FROM MyTable WHERE CONVERT(DateTime, Field3) > @startdate;
```

Comment: Same problem using CONVERT(DATETIME, Field3, 121). When used it SELECT it yields results, but causes error when used in the WHERE clause.

Comment: CONVERT is the same as CAST - either is used for explicit data type conversion

Comment: @clyc: Yep - I don't get it either

Comment: @OMG Ponies yep weird :) @Timonthy, try copying that script and running it on your environment. Let us know your results.

Comment: Yes, that works fine in my environment as well. However, if I insert a malformed date, and use the query SELECT field1, field2, CAST(field3 AS DATETIME) FROM test it fails with the error I am receiving. This is what I would expect in my database as well if the data was malformed, however I can use CAST in the SELECT without a problem.

Comment: How about you wrap that where clause in a case statement?

Comment: It works! However the case did not filter out ANY of my records. I tried where > @startDate and where < @startDate and added them together. The results are exactly the same as the number of records in the entire table. I'm still at a loss as to why it works with the case, even though the case isn't doing any filtering.

Answer (score 1):

Consider forcing specific dateformat using `SET DATEFORMAT ymd`

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify that the problem is not with the data (it usually is, with this error), try executing the following statement.  If you get some rows outputted then that data is likely the cause of the error.

```
      select * from myTable where isdate(FIELD3)=0
```